# Hibernate.initialize(obj) with exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two associated classes:

```
class City
{
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "city" )
    private List<Place> places;
}

class Place
{
    @ManyToOne
    private City city;
}
```

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public String home(Model model)
{
    for ( City city : citiesService.getAllCities() ) //  reading cities from data base
    {
        Hibernate.initialize(city.getPlaces());
    }
    model.addAttribute("cities", citiesService.getAllCity());
    return "home";
}
```

And in view I'm going to get something like this:

```
City1
 - Place1
 - Place2
 - Place3
 - ..
City2
 -Place1
 -Place2
 - ...
```

But I got an exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
```

When I used FetchType.EAGER instead of LAZY it worked fine ( of course without Hibernate.initialize() )

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT:

So, I have to have two methods in service layer:

```
public List<City> getAllTCitiesWithPlaces()
{
        List<City> cities = citiesDao.getAll();
        for ( City city : cities )
            Hibernate.initialize(city.getPlaces());
        return cities;
}
```

and

```
public List<City> getAllTCitiesWithoutPlaces()
{
       return citiesDao.getAll();
}
```

Yes ?

And thank You bro ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening because `Session` is already closed and city entity is detached from the session when you are fetching  places in the controller class.

Call `Hibernate.initialize(city.getPlaces());` in the same method where  you are getting cities.